# How do I get the coordinates of my data frame always in long/lat?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, coordinate-system

I want to determine the coordinates of my current data frame. To do so I wrote this script:

```
def DataFrame ():

  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
  df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
  return mxd,df

def Center (df):

  extent = df.extent 
  xmin = extent.XMin
  xmax = extent.XMax
  ymin = extent.YMin
  ymax = extent.YMax

  x = xmax - ((xmax - xmin)/2)
  y = ymax - ((ymax - ymin)/2)
  return x,y
```

As long as I am working with a geographic coordinate system, the results will be exactly the longitude and latitude. But as soon as I have a projected coordinate system it will return map units (i.e. meters). How can I avoid that problem? I always need to get lon/lat independend on the maps projection.

Comment: Have you looked at the [**Convert Coordinate Notation**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000tw000000) tool?

Comment: Hmm, as far as I understand it right, this would mean that I have to create tables for the values that can then be converted. I was hoping that there is a much easier way like just using "arcpy.convertCoordinates" or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `projectAs` function available on your [`Extent`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extent/018z00000072000000/) object:

```
extent_geographic = df.extent.projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)) # GCS_WGS_1984
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! Works perfectly.

Comment: I thought there was an easier way.

Comment: Ok, now I am feeling dumb. When I tried it some hours ago, it worked in my script and also in the python window. Now I tried again and suddenly I get the Error message: "Runtime error <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'Extent' object has no attribute 'projectAs'".

Comment: That's strange. See if you can reproduce it and send it to ESRI as a bug report. I would get a different error if I tried to use arcpy.SpatialReference("GCS_WGS_1984") -- for some reason it didn't like that but the SRID worked fine.